# elasticsearch - sum of total amount is greater than some amount using aggregation

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, group-by, kibana

I am trying to get the records where my aggregation total is greater than some amount say 1000. Below are the documents sample.

```
 [
  {
    "_index": "orders_stage",
    "_type": "order",
    "_id": "AV3FtHR8lArSPNJl_rcp",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "total_amount": 650,
      "custid": "2",
      "client_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "orders_stage",
    "_type": "order",
    "_id": "AV3F5UfjlArSPNJl_rlu",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "total_amount": 200,
      "custid": "1",
      "client_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "orders_stage",
    "_type": "order",
    "_id": "AV3F5UfjlArSPNJl_rxm",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "total_amount": 1400,
      "custid": "1",
      "client_id": 1
    }
  }
]
```

So first of all, I am grouping(agg) the records using custid and then I want those records whose sum of total_amount is greater than some amount say 1000. I have tried the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "client_id": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "amount_spent": {
              "gte": 1000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "customers": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "custid"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "amount_spent": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "total_amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this query I am not getting anything, Can somebody please guide me to filter on aggregation results.

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo: `amount_spent` should be `total_amount` in your `range` query

Comment: If I make it total_amount there, it won't return sum of total amount is greater 1000, instead it will only check for each record as I already mentioned I want to group and then apply the filter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a [`bucket_selector` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html), you cannot do it in the query part:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "client_id": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "customers": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "custid"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "amount_spent": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "total_amount"
          }
        },
        "amount_spent_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "amountSpent": "amount_spent"
            },
            "script": "params.amountSpent > 1000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Comment: can you please also guide me to get unique bucket counts as it is returning the first level aggegation count i.e. 2 in the above example, it must return 1 as we are filtering the records > 1000, thanks

Comment: You're not filtering the records, but the buckets, which is not the same

Comment: so is there any way so that I can get all the bucket counts in multiple aggregation?

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question (since this one is closed) referencing this one and explain your exact needs.